# Not able to fecth the data from google api token verifier in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, google-api

I am using the token verifier google api

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123

and it is giving me the user email id in the browser like

```
{
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

Now I want to call this URL from my back end code and retrieve the mail id for doing authentication

I tried something like this

```
function(string access_token){
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" + access_token;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
 request.Method = "GET";
 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
 {
  using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
   {
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

   }
  }
}
```

But not able to get the data from that json

Any alternatives?

I just need to get the email id of the user with access_token or idToken which the client will be sending to the server.

Comment: Why are you using a XmlTextReader and expecting to be able to read Json?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

used WebClient for getting data from browser

after deserializing I got the data.